# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" but no token is specified, the error is indicated to be on whitespace

Tags: react-native, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I'm following [this tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/getting-started-with-react-native-in-2019-build-your-first-app-a41ebc0617e2) as I'm a beginner at React Native (and Javascript for that matter), and I'm running into an "Unexpected token" syntax error, but it does not tell me which character is unexpected. I've pasted my code below as well as the error message. Am I doing something totally wrong here?

**EmojiDict.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class EmojiDict extends Component {
  state = {
    'A': 'A Smiley',
    'B': 'B Rocket',
    'C': 'C Atom Symbol'
  };

  render() {
    return {
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{this.state['A']}</Text>
      </View>
    };
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

export default EmojiDict;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import EmojiDict from './src/components/EmojiDict';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <EmojiDict />;
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
error: SyntaxError: /Users/johnking/Documents/Projects/HelloWorld/src/components/EmojiDict.js: Unexpected token (13:6)

  11 |   render() {
  12 |     return {
> 13 |       <View style={styles.container}>
     |       ^
  14 |           <Text>{this.state['A']}</Text>
  15 |       </View>
  16 |     };
```

Comment: Remove "{" and "}" in `return` block

Comment: Use render() {
  return ();
} 
instead of render() {
  return {}     
   };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be return () instead {}.

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{this.state['A']}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you! Just purely for learning purposes, is there ever a case where braces would be used (different version of ES)? I copied the code from the tutorial that's why i'm wondering, so I want to understand why parenthesis are used here.

Comment: If this answer help you, select it becomes [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please. Return have to return only one big tag like a component,{} usually works like javascript or an object, () means only to wrap up the View tag. And you can see at [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator)  example at "Class Component Example"

Comment: I know where is the problem. When you copy `render() {return <EmojiDict />};` this, you mistake treat {} as (). It because ` <EmojiDict />` is only one tag, didn't have to wrap it, so it omit (), it can work same as `render() {return (<EmojiDict />);}`